# How to determine why a payload is blocked by F5 ASM

Tags: f5-big-ip

we are a web development team and recently we have our application deployed on an environment that is behind a F5 firewall with ASM policy enabled.

We have experienced situation where our HTTP calls are being blocked and the networking team is advising us that we need to whitelist our URL on the F5 platform. However although the URL is whitelisted, we still getting random blocked showing a message with a Support ID.

By simulating the scenario, we are able to capture the payload that we sent that was block, but is there anyway for us to check which signature that causes the block to happen?

The `asm_module.xml` was provided to us, is there any tools that we can use to simulate the scenario?

Comment: Shouldn't you take your support ID to the network team or vendor, and ask them why the calls are blocked?

Comment: Tried that, and was told to look for ourselves and has the `asm_modules.xml` sent to us..